# Image upload with validation on EF Code First models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I could've sworn this should've been answered a million times before, but I've come up empty after searching for quite a while.

I have a view that is bound to an object. This object should have an image attached to it somehow (I don't have any preferred method). I want to validate the image file. I've seen ways to do this with attributes, for example:

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
            {
                return img.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, that requires the type of HttpPostedFileBase on the property in the model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

That's all well and good, but I can't really use this type in a EF Code First model class, as it's not really suitable for database storage.

So what's the best approach for this?

Comment: Yes that is the whole point of having a My **ViewModel**. That you use your ViewModels in your views. And you create separate types for your entities and you do the mapping between them manually or with something like Automapper.

Comment: I had not heard of that before (I'm only a few days into MVC development). I actually thought of another solution that worked for me. I posted it below

Comment: But isn't it a lot of extra work to have ViewModels for all the models? Doesn't it kind of defeat the purpose of the DRY way of doing things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I got a little further with development of the site, it was inevitable that I started using ViewModels. Creating a model for each view is definately the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out it was a quite simple solution.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [NotMapped, ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PNG image smaller than 1MB")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

I set the NotMapped attribute tag to prevent it from being saved in the database. Then in my controller, I get the HttpPostedFileBase in my object model:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(product);
        }
        // Save the file on filesystem and set the filepath in the object to be saved in the DB.
    }
```